# Aligning a Box to a Box with CSS

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and I am trying to make my first website as css but I am having a problem getting the two boxes to align side by side for the body and the four boxes above that don't stay next to each other. I have played around with Float and position with no luck.

You can see the site here: http://gdisinc.com/barker/default.php

I'm trying to get it to look like this: http://gdisinc.com/barker/images/menubar/layout_barker.jpg

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: @SperanskyDanil well if you look at the image of what I want this site to look like you will notice the four boxes below the header and nice and tight together. And then the two boxes below that (body) are side by side. But in my actual site I am building the four boxes have spaces and the two below that aren't aligned side by side.

Answer (score 1):

just updated your `css` with my `css` that will work perfectly there were few `bugs` you made so i sort it out those points so now its working fine updated your with mentioned below `css` :-

**CSS**

```
div#main {
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 902px;
}

div#outerbox {
    background-color: #A2282C;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 660px;
}

div#innerbox {
    background-color: #4D1516;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 277px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 640px;
}

div#sideouterbox {
    background-color: #A2282C;
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    height: 300px;
    width: 222px;
}
```

Comment: That was it. Couple things because I like to learn could you explain what I did wrong please? Also the four boxes above these two how can I get them so that they but up against each other? Thank you very much!!

Comment: @FrankG. you can come in this room i will explain few points because its long talk can't explain in short anwers :-) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15567/css

Answer (score 0):

First you're at the very limit in box width, try making it a bit smaller

after that use

```
display:inline-block;
```

if the sum of the boxes width fit in the container you should have no problem.

Hope this helps

Comment: btw, you should use this for both elements (boxes in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Solution without floats and weird overflow:hidden statements, just standard positioning...

```
div#main {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative
    width: 902px;
}

div#outerbox {
    border: 2px solid white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 669px;
    background-color: #A2282C;
    position: absolute;
}

div#innerbox {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 277px;
    background-color: #4D1516;
}

div#sideouterbox {
    border: 2px solid white;
    height: 300px;
    width: 222px;
    background-color: #A2282C;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

div#sideinnerbox {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 280px;
    width: 198px;
    background-color: #4D1516;
}
```

Just copy this over your styles and you should be fine.